# Bootstrap select input field print

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to print my page, that i created with bootstrap.
And on the page i have select input control.

When it's printed... it has little triangle, that implicates this field is select field. But i do not want to set this information printed.

Do anyone know how to remove this triangle from printing? [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGrqC.png)

And here is how my code looks:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="hidden-print">Wybierz z listy </span><!-- todo Radiobutton-->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select name="RAdiagnosisSelect"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    multiple-limit="1"
                                    ng-model="visit.diagnosisId"
                                    ng-disabled="!technical.firstVisit && visit.RADiagnosis!=2"
                                    required>
                                <option value="1">M05.8 Inne sero-dodatnie reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów</option>
                                <option value="2">M06.0 Surowiczoujemne reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów</option>
                                <!--<option value="3">M06.1 Choroba Stilla u osoby dorosłej</option>-->
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And i'm using normal printing library:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest i did it in other way.
I've split the visible part and printing part.

And got one code from showing the user content, second to printing.

It worked well, so i do not have problem with formatting.

So, the answer is: use hidden-print, and visible-print :).

Answer (score 0):

Write this style

```
<style>
@media print {
.caret {display:none;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: It did not make a difference. Still visible in print. I have attached it good to the site. (Becouse other changes work)

Answer (score 0):

You may hide it behind another element, for instance :before

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wztvk02t/5/)

Wrap your select with a div:

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 29px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  background: white;
  top:1px;
  right:1px;
  z-index: 1; 
}

.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.select {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="hidden-print">Wybierz z listy </span><!-- todo Radiobutton-->
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="select-wrapper">
                            <select name="RAdiagnosisSelect"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    multiple-limit="1"
                                    ng-model="visit.diagnosisId"
                                    ng-disabled="!technical.firstVisit && visit.RADiagnosis!=2"
                                    required>
                                <option value="1">M05.8 Inne sero-dodatnie reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów</option>
                                <option value="2">M06.0 Surowiczoujemne reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów</option>
                                <!--<option value="3">M06.1 Choroba Stilla u osoby dorosłej</option>-->
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it worked, now i don't have this triangle... But it is still visible in printing. So it helped around 50% - but the wrong 50%. Any more ideas? :).

Comment: well, another solution may be making div.select-wrapper wider than div.input-group and assign overflow:hidden to the last one, but that results into bad looking dropdown options. Also, if that ok to your project you may use something like https://select2.github.io/examples.html - this plugin converts select into block html structure so you're in control for everything and can simply hide the triangle with display:none